# Assign const ref to non-const object

Tags: c++

In the following code we are returning a const object and collecting it in a non const object, and still it compiles without an error or a warning..

```
class foo
{
    int i;
public:
    const foo& call() const
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo aa, bb;
    bb = aa.call();
}
```

Comment: BTW, question titles such as "Why does this work?" are discouraged in favour of more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 15):

You're actually taking a copy of a const object when you do `bb = aa.call( )` which will call the implicit copy constructor on `foo`.

If you wanted to break the compilation then try:

```
foo aa;
foo& bb = aa.call( );
```

**Note:**

The implicit copy constructor is generally defined as:

```
foo( const foo& exist );
```

and in the default case just does a *member-wise* copy.

Comment: You might want to explain why a copy is being made

Comment: "shallow copy" isn't necessarily correct. It does a member-wise copy, so you'll get a shallow copy if and only if it contains at least one raw pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This code calls the implicitly defined copy assign operator `foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)`:

```
    int main()
    {
        foo aa, bb;
        bb = aa.call();//  equivalent to bb.operator=(aa.call());
    }
```

The argument to that assign operator is a const reference to foo, so can bind directly the reference returned by foo::call. There is no copy constructor called in any of this code.